# Using CSS Flexbox's `justify-content:space-between` but left-aligning last row

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a simple grid of boxes that I would like to responsively space with Flexbox.

The number of boxes is generated by the user, so I need something to work dynamically. [Here's a codepen snippet](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdeYzL) of where I'm at:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.thumb{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:black;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

Here's what it looks like with the code above:

[image: Flexbox last line left-align]

Here's what I'd like it to look like:

[image]

How can this be achieved with flexbox? I want to avoid % margins and let flexbox do all the work here if possible as it works really nicely in a responsive setting.

Comment: Nope...not possible...it's come up before and the top row is not alignable like that.

Comment: You mean the bottom row @Paulie_D? That's disappointing, have been googling around and can't find any discussion. Any proposed workarounds?

Comment: No, you can get the last row to do that **but** not with the alignment of the top row as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do it, but at the expense of spoiling a little bit the DOM.
Insert filler elements (as many as the maximum number elements that will fit in a row) with a height of 0, and you have it

```css
.wrap{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.thumb{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:black;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}


.filler{
  width:150px;
  height:0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
</div>
```